# Karp Reduction Between Subset Sum Problem And Vaccine Problem

Tags: time-complexity, polynomials, reduction

I am supposed to show that the following problem is NP-complete by Karp reducing it to the Subset Sum Problem. The problem is to distribute vaccine doses among different age groups according to:

Given: D vaccine doses, n age groups, a1 to an as input, where age group k consists of ak individuals, d1 to dn as input and each individual in age group k receives dk doses, at least tk percent of each age group must be fully vaccinated, and the maximal number of left-over doses can be S.

I am supposed to prove this problem is NP-complete. One of the steps is making a Karp reduction between this problem and the Subset Sum problem. I have tried to do this reduction in various ways but not been successful. Any ideas? Pseudo-code would be ideal.

Note: The Subset Sum problem receives the following input: A set of positive integers and a target K. The goal is to find a subset of the set of integers which sum up to K.